# how to get the value of h:outputtext inside ui repeat using command button jsf primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to know how to get an output text value that is is populated using a list and is nested inside a ui repeat using a one command button per element to send the data to display the output of the selected element in another page?
I searched in google and watched videos but I still did not get it.

Comment: Hello and welcome. There's not nearly enough information in your question to give a proper answer. For example what do you want to happen after you "get" that text? What's the relationship between the button and the text? (e.g. is there only one button or one per list element). Why do you want to take the value from the `outputtext` instead of taking it from the backend list that generated those `outputtext`s?

Comment: To sum it up, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and an accurate description of what you want to happen.